# Как отцентрировать текст внутри блока по всем осям

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Текст не центрируется у блока `post__name` никаким образом. Я пробовал через `text-aling: center;` так же пробовал через флексы, но ничего не меняется

Тут код:
https://codepen.io/realHikkan/pen/KKgdmKR?editors=1100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно просто навесить 'align-items: center' и 'justify-content: center', на родительский блок '.post__name'.
То есть:

```
  .post__content {
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
```